# bundle install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundle-install

I'm trying to install this gem: https://github.com/jongilbraith/simple-private-messages with bundle install.

And I'm getting the following error message:

```
Updating git://github.com/professionalnerd/simple-private-messages.git
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'simple-private-messages (>= 0, runtime)' in git://github.com/professionalnerd/simple-private-messages.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'simple-private-messages (>= 0, runtime)'
```

entry in `Gemfile`:

`gem "simple-private-messages",:git =>"git://github.com/professionalnerd/simple-private-messages.git"`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per @bjeanes answer, ideally the Git repository should have a `.gemspec` file for each gem the Git repository represents.

However, if the repository is only missing the `.gemspec` file and would otherwise be a valid Git gem source, you can specify a version number in your `gem` call to have Bundler generate a `.gemspec` for you:

```
gem 'simple-private-messages', '0.0.0', :git => 'git://github.com/jongilbraith/simple-private-messages.git'
```

Answer (score 1):

The git repo needs to have a .gemspec file in it in order to be a valid gem.