# Getting dependencies of git repo without .gemspec with bundler

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm trying to install a git version of heckle using bundler.

At first I tried

```
gem "heckle", :github => 'phiggins/heckle', :branch => "ruby_parser"
```

But that didn't work, with

```
Could not find gem 'heckle (>= 0) ruby' in git://github.com/phiggins/heckle.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'heckle (>= 0) ruby'
```

I then specified the version of heckle, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/3952045/38765 but bundler doesn't try installing any dependencies of heckle:

```
$ bundle exec heckle
```

gives me

```
cannot load such file -- ruby_parser (LoadError)
```

How do I tell bundler to find heckle's dependencies when there isn't a .gemspec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. How would bundler know the dependencies when `.gemspec` is where the dependencies are supposed to be found.

If you look at the heckle `Rakefile` you will see:

```
dependency 'ruby_parser', '~> 2.3.1'
dependency 'ruby2ruby', '~> 1.3.0'
dependency 'ZenTest',   '~> 4.7.0'
```

You just have to add those manually to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'ruby_parser', '~> 2.3.1'
gem 'ruby2ruby',   '~> 1.3.0'
gem 'ZenTest',     '~> 4.7.0'
```

Comment: With just a line of Ruby you don't even need to do those manually.  Just read the file, replace dependency with gem, and write the result to the GemFile.